# Nativescript not compiling app after upgrade to v8 - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, nativescript

I upgraded an Nativescript project from v7 to v8.
Had to upgrade npm as well (now 10.2.4) and node to 21.6.0

Now when I do an ns build «platform» - I get the following error:

resolving "./app/app.scss" to "./app/app.ios.scss"

<--- Last few GCs --->

[16754:0x7ff1b0008000]    56755 ms: Mark-Compact 4076.5 (4143.4) -> 4076.0 (4143.4) MB, 1652.96 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.215, current mu = 0.011) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed

[16754:0x7ff1b0008000]    59306 ms: Mark-Compact 4077.9 (4143.4) -> 4077.5 (4150.4) MB, 2537.71 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.103, current mu = 0.005) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----

1: 0x10b476fc0 node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
2: 0x10b64ca7c v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
3: 0x10b84ce47 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
4: 0x10b84a978 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
5: 0x10b8402bb v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
6: 0x10b840b75 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
7: 0x10b8221b2 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/usr/local/bin/node]
8: 0x10bc83d29 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
9: 0x10c0b5636 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/usr/local/bin/node]

I tried to increase the memory with `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096` to ridiculous amounts of memory - still getting that error.

Since the error seems to occur when the scss files are compiled, I also tried to add an empty app.ios.scss file - still getting that error...

Any ideas?

[Edit]

I also tried to empty the app.js file - still getting that error. My guess is, that there must be something wrong with the sass-compiler, although I emptied the sass-files, too.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by updating the sass and sass-loader modules.

[Edit] Nope - it only worked temporarily - bug is back :(